# Remove tax from grand total

Tags: tax, totals, grand-total

I need to remove tax from grand total in Magento.
Means I want only show Tax but not add grand total

[image]

Answer (score 4):

you can managed this settign from admin

Go to `admin>System>Configuration>Sales>Tax>Shopping Cart Display Settings`

make `Display Subtotal=Excluding Tax`

enter image description here

you can managed tax display setting on cart page,from here :

`admin>System>Configuration>Sales>Tax>Shopping Cart Display Setting`

===================================================================
How to do this (programatically)....

Under `{magento_base}/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/tax/checkout/`

Edit file `grandtotal.phtml` 
(I suggest you make a backup of the file just in case).

Find the line:

```
<?php if ($this->includeTax() && $this->getTotalExclTax()>=0):?>
```

Delete the subsequent lines:

```
<tr>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
        <strong><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Grand Total Excl. Tax')?></strong>
    </td>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right">
        <strong><?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getTotalExclTax()) ?></strong>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This change means it will now only show the tax inclusive line in the cart review.

Comment: I have already setup above setting but not working.

Comment: My quetion is "Remove tax from grant total"

Comment: Kindly look attach image.I need "Grant total = $599"

Comment: I need Grant total show $599 according above image.also it goes same in checkout page means payment section otherwise it gives error.

Comment: than remove tax completely. no tax than no calculation.

Comment: I want only show calculation but not include in anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

You change your settings under **System > Configuration > Sales > Tax**

**Calculation Settings:** Catalog Prices - Including Tax

**Price Display Settings:**  Display Product Prices In Catalog - Including Tax

**Shopping Cart Display Settings:**  Include Tax In Grand Total -  Yes

**Orders, Invoices, Credit Memos Display Settings:**  Display Prices - Including Tax

keep other settings defaults.